# Prevent automatic table creation or drop when using `JdbcChannelMessageStore`

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-jdbc

We want to use a `JdbcChannelMessageStore` to have a persisted queue in our application.

However, the sql scripts which are included in `spring-integration-jdbc` causing automatic creation (and dropping ?) of the following DB objects:

```
  INT_MESSAGE_IX1 
  INT_CHANNEL_MSG_DATE_IDX 
  INT_CHANNEL_MSG_PRIORITY_IDX 
  INT_MESSAGE 
  INT_MESSAGE_GROUP 
  INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE 
  INT_LOCK 
  INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE 
  INT_METADATA_STORE 
  INT_MESSAGE_SEQ
```

This is not a behavior which we wont to have in production. There we have to control everything what happens on our data bases.

Is there a way to prevent the loading of those scripts?

Thanks a lot in advance for your reply.

Comment: Hi, the database strategy is controlled with "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" property. You can set it to "none" if you want no automatic schema updates, "validate" if you just want to check it at application startup "update" or "create-drop" are often used in developpement phase as it simplify database schema updates but should be planned action in production. So try "none"...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gweltaz Niquel I have found out that the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set by default to `create-drop` when an in-memory data base is used. And in fact I saw this behavior when using H2 DB.

For external data bases, the default setting is `none`

[image]